# Lost WiFi when loaded into my HP Laptop

Tags: networking, wireless

I have loaded Ubuntu/Linux 14.04LTS onto my HP Laptop. I did a dual boot with Windows 8.1. Using Windows I have a WiFi connection. When I shut down and reboot into the Ubuntu/Linux I then loose my entire WiFi connection. When I go to the Network Icon in the Linux I only get a dialog box showing that I can only connect using a Ethernet cable.
I have tried to manually enter my ISP and WEP key and still can not connect.
Did I miss out on something when installing the OS. The drivers seem to be missing.
I am also a complete novice to computing and really don't know how to enter any code or where to enter code if it needs it.
I would appreciate any information that someone could provide. I see lots of people posting a similar problem but I don't see the correct fix.
Thank you,
Ted

Comment: "I am also a complete novice to computing" ...then installing Ubuntu wasn't one of the best things to do... Try opening a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and enter `rfkill unblock all`, then hit Enter. Report back whether you are then able to connect to the WiFi.

Comment: Edit the file /etc/network/interfaces and remove any references to your wireless card then reboot. Does network manager control your wifi now ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lshw -c net`  You can just copy the highlighted command with your mouse/touchpad and CTRL + c to copy but you need to use CTRL + Shift + p to paste into terminal.  Also in terminal you can highlight the results with mouse/touchpad and use CTRL + Shift + c to copy

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with an HP laptop, I was able to connect via network cable and download the solution following the instructions on this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx?action=show&redirect=BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29), works great now! Hope this helps!
12.04 (Precise Pangolin) - 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)

Open a Terminal and if you haven't already done so, update your package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you have a b43 card use the command

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

or, if you need the b43legacy driver, use:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

or, (12.04 - 12.10) if you need a LP-PHY version (e.g BCM4312), use:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Restart the computer

Comment: Link only answers are highly discuoraged here, could you please copy-paste the instructions that were helpful for you, also use a link to refer to the original page..

Comment: @guntbert: i have found it to be from ubuntu community wiki thats why i suggest copy-pasting, you are right though :)

Comment: @heemayl indeed :-) I didn't look closely - I presumed you were pasting your own version of a canned comment.

Comment: Thanks @heemayl ! I'm a linux noob, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all for your help !! As a non terminal user it all went great for the install of the Broadcom driver. But... i now have a problem with it staying connected. I connect and then loose the connection and then it goes back on automatically...Any suggestions ??